# Burninate or clean up the tag [dual]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

We currently have 48 [questions tagged dual](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual).

There questions are on different subjects:

- Dual ISPs
- Dual dual mail accounts
- Dual monitors
- Dual graphics cards
- Dual boot
- Dual OS installations (installation, time synchronisation, ...)

I suggest to retag a few of them (e.g. to [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors), [multi-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot)) and to burn the tag because it is way to vague and does not add anything to the questions.

Comment: Suggested witty title: The two of us should burninate [dual]

Comment: Let's NOT have a [dual]!

Comment: Remember, witty title = upvotes. Boring title = sadness

Comment: @CanadianLuke [BEWARE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283072/blacklist-the-whole-internet?noredirect=1#comment140801_283072)

Comment: Just a general reminder -- please don't start cleaning up a tag until there is some consensus and the [status-planned] tag has been applied. I saw a handful of edits in the suggested edit queue this morning that were going ahead and making the changes suggested in this post.